# Java - calling a method of an object not in scope (parent's children)

Tags: java, swing, scope

This may have been asked many times before or I don't know what to search for to get an answer. What I have got is a JFrame that loads in several JPanels. What I am having difficulty in is updating the contents of one JPanel from another. So say I have the following:

```
JFrame1.JPanel1.JButtonA
JFrame1.JPanel2.JButtonB
```

When JButtonA is pressed I want JButtonB to have its text changed. Of course this isn't what I want to do but is a simple example of what I would like to achieve. Where am I going wrong? How to get a reference to an object without making everything a singleton?

Comment: Can you please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? It is always better to discuss it based on your code than any abstract answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is of course to remember a reference to `JFrame1` when construction `JPanel1`:

```
JPanel1 p1 = new JPanel1(this);
```

and remember and use that in JPanel1:

```
public JPanel1(JFrame1 f1) {
    this.f1 = f1;
}
...
public void actionPerformend(...) {
    f1.getPanel2().getButtonB().setText("A is pressed");
}
```

But **that's bad**.

Instead, think about what clicking A really means (for example *pauze game*). Then create a `PauzeGameEventListener` interface, implemented by JPanel2 (for example *the chessboard*) and make JPanel1 (for example *the game controls panel*) fire a `PauzeGameEvent` to all listeners. That way, when your JPanel3 (for example *score panel*) or non-gui stuff (for example *the AI player*) needs to be aware of that too, you're not littering the JPanel1 code.

Comment: +1 nice explanation. Though you have to read it twice to get it :)

Comment: @Boro: +1 Agree. Conveniently, all `JComponent`s have an [`EventListenerList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html), and the API shows how to implement support for such a custom listener.

Comment: I forgot to mention that it's the GoF design pattern **Observer**.